# Parse continuous output of a long-running command

Tags: unix, long-running-processes

I could not find similar question, so decided to post it

I have a long running job (*nix environment):

```
program > job.out
```

which is running over days and prints output in chunks. Can I instead of "job.out" have a script (maybe Perl?) that will modify chunked output (for example prepend a timestamp) and write it to job.out.

Answer (score 2):

```
program | perl -ne 'printf("%s %s",time,$_)' > job.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can. Just do it like this:

```
program | perl myperlscript.pl > job.out
```

In the perl script, just accept input from stdin and write to stdout.

Comment: *"However, the perl script will not start until program is complete."* - not true, the shell will start both of the piped processes at the same time.